# jquery tablesorter: updating headers

Tags: tablesorter

The table headers will change depending on dynamic ajax updates. When doing this using:

```
$('table thead').html(headers);
```

and then re-initialising the table using:

```
$("table").tablesorter({ theme : 'blue', sortList: [[2,1],[0,0]] });
```

The ability to sort is removed from the headers. How can I update the headers and re-initialise it so that those headers are treated correctly?

Comment: Is the entire table being replaced, or just the headers?

Comment: Just the headers and some of the rows. I didn't want to replace the entire table as there are hidden rows that I want to maintain state on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you might need to destroy the instance of tablesorter before re-initializing it:

```
// initialisation
var initOptions = {
  theme: 'blue',
  sortList: [[2,1],[0,0]]
};
$("table").tablesorter(initOptions);
```

Then after the ajax update, use:

```
// Remove tablesorter and all classes
$("table").trigger("destroy", [false, function(){
  // callback after the destroy method
  $('table thead').html('<tr>' + headers + '</tr>');
  $("table").tablesorter(initOptions);
}]);
```

In this example, make sure the `initOptions` variable is within the same closure as the initialisation code, or just duplicate it ;)

Comment: I just wanted to add a note to say that your edit is correct in that you can't update the `thead` before using the `destroy` method, because the destroy method will restore the headers to the way they were originally (saved in `table.config.headerContent`).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!! Although, I am additionally using tablesorterPager (alongwith sorting and filtering) which makes it a bit complicated. Please suggest if you have a workaround for my problem.